# opencv 3.0.0 programming in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

I have been troubled by the problem these days. I want to write opencv-3.0.0  programs with C language in the terminal of my ubuntu 14.04 in the VM. While,  in early days, I have installed Qt. Now, In order that my program is not  affected by the Qt library function, I shielded the path variables of Qt in the  /etc/bash.bashrc file. A simple example is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
  Mat img = imread("cornea.jpg");
  imshow("src, img");
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it with gcc-5.3.0 by using this command:

> g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv`

And then I have the result:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   /usr/bin/ld: warning: libicudata.so.54, needed by //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_clone_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘uenum_next_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_strToLower_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getStandardName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_setAttribute_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_setMillis_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_strcoll_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_setSubstChars_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getTimeZoneDisplayName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openCountryTimeZones_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_fromUnicode_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_open_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getDefaultName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_open_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_inDaylightTime_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucol_getSortKey_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getAvailableName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_get_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openTimeZoneIDEnumeration_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getDSTSavings_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_open_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_openTimeZones_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_toUnicode_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_strToUpper_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘u_errorName_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘uenum_close_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_countAvailable_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getMaxCharSize_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_getAlias_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucal_getDefaultTimeZone_54’未定义的引用
>   //home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5：对‘ucnv_compareNames_54’未定义的引用
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The backticks in command line `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs opencv` is invisible.I have not got the reason now.

Why this error is related to Qt. And can you help me solve it?

Comment: My friend, I tried your method: sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev, but failed and the same error! I always doubt the path of gcc. Why the compiler always finds gcc in Qt5? Of course,the path "/home/lmk/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc" is  s where I installed my Qt5, but I have installed a new gcc successfully. Using the command line: which gcc, the answer is /usr/gcc-5.0.0/bin/gcc. Could you please think of other ways?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is with `libcui` packages which is needed by `qt`. I guess it is missing in your system. Try an attempt for installing `libcui` with `sudo apt-get install libicu-dev`. 1st line in your error `warning: libicui18n.so.54, needed by libQt5Core.so.5, not found` implies it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libicu-dev` `libicu-dev is the latest version`, also failed. In my question, I have said: in order that my program is not affected by the Qt library function, I shielded the path variables of Qt in the /etc/bash.bashrc file. Do you have heard of compiling opencv program only with gcc? Open this [link](blog.csdn.net/pzhsunxu/article/details/17913885)  and you will get my meaning. I do not want my program have something to do with Qt. because later I will package my C language program for the call of java interface on Andriod platform.

Comment: Your `Qt` library paths may be shielded correctly but it is not finding the correct path to the other library `libcui`. Find the path of `libcui` packages and include the path manually via `-rpath`. I am not sure whether this will work or not.

Comment: The path of libicu is the subpath of my Qt5 installation. Why? Why do my   opencv program of showing pictures will have a relationship with Qt5?  In your opinion, can the opencv program compiling be independent of Qt? This is the essence of my question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to compile without `Qt`

Comment: OK,that means you agree with me. Do you have some other methods for my problem of making my opencv program independent of Qt? The error above troubles me these days!

Comment: Sorry friend, I gave up. I couldn't find any solution. Wait some experts in SO may help you

Comment: Having surfed on the internet these days, but no gain. Many thanks to your sincere reply and looking forward next communication!